# PHP How to remove elements from an array and add to another array by key?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Not sure how to insert using `foreach` key deleted into new array

Function below

```
function array_delete_insert($delArrKey, $array1) {
//deletes from
    if(is_array($delArrKey)) {
        foreach ($delArrKey as $del_key => $del_value) {
            foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
                if ($value == $del_value) {
                    unset($array1[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
            if ($value == $delArrKey) {
                unset($array1[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return array_values($array1);

// returns new array with all the deleted items
    $array2 = //all deleted elements array
    return array_values($array2);
}

//Calling the function by

$array1 = array('apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'kiwi');
$delArrKey = array('orange', 'apple');
$new_arr = array_delete_insert($delArrKey, $array1);
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for `array_values(array_diff($array1, is_array($delArrKey) ? $delArrKey, array($delArrKey)))`

Comment: this only returns the non deleted elements... the goal is to return the deleted elements

Comment: Perhaps you could give the expected output for the input data you have, that would make it easier to determine exactly what you are trying to achieve? Other sample data would also help.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question but you could just array_push($newArray, $delItem) then return this.

For example:

```
$array1 = array('apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'blueberry', 'kiwi');
$delArrKey = array('orange', 'apple');
$new_arr = array_delete_insert($delArrKey, $array1);

function array_delete_insert($delArrKey, $array1) {
  $array2 = [];
  //deletes from
      if(is_array($delArrKey)) {
          foreach ($delArrKey as $del_key => $del_value) {
              foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
                  if ($value == $del_value) {
                      unset($array1[$key]);
                      array_push($array2, $value); //if item is deleted add to new array
                  }
              }
          }
      } else {
          foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
              if ($value == $delArrKey) {
                  unset($array1[$key]);
              }
          }
      }
    return array_values($array1);
  }
```

Not sure if you wanted the new deleted items array, but you can just add that variable to the return.